# VBA excel : Forcing filename with Workbook_BeforeSave and ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, save-as, before-save, xlsm

I am building a form that is placed in a shared folder on a private network. The 'mother form', used by a single user, is a template that generates 'child forms' when it is saved using the information from the spreadsheet.

To name my 'child forms', I use the Workbook_BeforeSave event. I collect the information I need to name the file. Then, I save as the name of my file. All the files are in the same folder.

My code works fine on my computer (Excel 2016) but for some reason, it doesn't work on all computers (I have noticed the problem on Excel 2013 but not on 2010).

I checked if every user had the correct access to the folder containing the files, and they have. They are not able to manualy save as.

Here is the code I'm using to save :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Cancel = True

'Variable definition
Dim Contrat As String
Dim Projet As String
Dim Requisition As String
Dim Marque As String
Dim RefPeinture As String

'Get variable values
Contrat = Feuil1.Range("C3").Value
Projet = Feuil1.Range("C4").Value
Requisition = Feuil1.Range("F5").Value
Marque = Feuil1.Range("F6").Value
RefPeinture = Feuil1.Range("C7").Value

'Determining file name
NomDeFichier = "F:\Peinture (Inspection)\Année actuelle\" & Contrat & "_" & Projet & "_" & RefPeinture & "_" & Requisition & "_" & Marque & ".xlsm"

'Saving as file name in .xlsm (fileformat = 52)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=NomDeFichier, _
    FileFormat:=52, _
    Password:="", _
    WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False

'Inserting document proporty for keyword
ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Keywords").Value = Feuil1.Range("C3").Value

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub